# Embedding blog content on site

Tags: jquery, html, css

I may be going about this the total wrong way, but I'm learning so it's a good experience overall. Here is my current problem:

I have a site, it has many components, one of which is a blog. I'm using flatpress to run the blog, it's simple and i like it. I've formatted the blog output/posts to be embedded on the main section of my site (it's more a design thing than function).

I'm not sure using iframes are a good idea, mostly because, if I ever choose to have an image in my blog posts, they use slimbox2 (lightbox clone), and when clicked, their overlay only opens inside the iframe. I'm not sure how to get them to open outside the iframe in the parent.

Alternatively, I was thinking I could embed the blog content using jquery, a la:

```
$("#testLoad").load("http://url/flatpress #content-main");
```

in a div container (it just looks garbled and isn't obeying any of the blog's css/scripting), so I can't get that to work and I'm looking for guidance on how to achieve having my blog content embedded and the image overlays to function correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Window.postMessage will allow you to send info like the picture from the iframe to the blogs main page.

postMessage documentation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage

1st demo I saw when I quickly googled it (haven't tried it but it looks correct)
http://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe

Comment: this sounds interesting, i'm not very experienced with DOM, and even jquery so I'm still sort of confused how I could implement this.

Answer (score 1):

The iFrame solution doesn't sound like what you really want, considering the use of the lightbox. Can you post a link so we can see what's going on with your CSS?

Comment: i wouldn't feel comfy doing that just because it's all a mess and not anonymized for scrutiny at the moment. i can do my best to explain it here though :/

Comment: i'm able to just use, `$("#testLoad").load("http://url/flatpress");` and my content appears with the correct formatting etc., except this code is essentially loading the blog page over everything else on the main page. i haven't found a way to contain it inside a div, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: it seems like you would normally pull the entry onto the page server-side with php -- is there a reason you are not using php and instead trying to bring the posts in on the front end?

Comment: ok so, i've anonymized it enough, take a look and you'll know what i'm trying to do...http://bakedpota.to/